# Angular - router only on mobile. Multi modules view on PC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, url-routing

I want to create single page application with modules on accordions, when you click they expand. But this needs to be different over mobile.
So on mobile devices, when you click accordion, instead of collapsing, it should go to same content, but in new page (URL routing).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm rather trying to figure out, how to control those. I know how to set accordion, its not a point here.

Let's say i have 4 modules. Module1, 2, 3, 4.

For PC:
- all modules will be shown on '/#' main route. All data calculation will happen for all of them
For Mobile
- only links to modules will be show on the page.
- every module will be shown after clicking and routing /#/module1/:data

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {

 controller : main controller, which load all other modules, and shows them on page
// but on mobile, show only links to it

}
when('/module1', {
  // only if mobile
  // load certain module only
```

So every module will have 2 things:
- mobile view ( on separated page )
- pc view, on main page

By saying module i don't necessary mean ng module.

I'm just not sure to handle that correctly. 
I was thinking about router with some rules over controller and on resolve, or maybe about using $states.